# Backbone click event not working correctly in firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, events, backbone.js

This code executes perfectly in safari and chrome but has problems with Firefox.

Basically, I have a group of radio buttons. 
This click event should only be fired if the radio button has an attribute of checked. However for some reason, the radio button in firefox seems to fire the event even when the radio-button is not checked.

```
var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({

    events: {
        'click input[type="radio"]:checked' : 'radioListener',
    },

     radioListener : function(evt) {
         var selectedObject =  evt.currentTarget;
         $(selectedObject).prop('checked', false);
         $(selectedObject).val('');
         $(selectedObject).change(this.clearSelection(evt));
    }

 });
```

Comment: What is the code for "this.clearSelection(evt)". Also, what is the scope of radioListener? Is it bound to the JQuery event or is the scope of the View?  Can you confirm that the "clearSelection" method is getting invoked?

Comment: Sorry, I should of been clearer with the question, edited now. The problem is that this event is firing in firefox when the attribute is not checked

Comment: When is the event firing? Are you saying it's fired when the page is loaded?

Comment: The problem is that the event should only be fired when a checked radio button has been clicked. The problem is that in firefox the event is triggered on unchecked radio buttons as well.

Answer (score 1):

You have wrong understanding of how event binding works.

When you bind event listener to DOM element, jQuery selector (`input[type="radio"]:checked` in your case) you provide is used to specify DOM element during event **binding**, not event **firing** (triggering). 
This mean that in your example `click` event is fired on the selected radio buttons regardless of whether they checked at clicking moment.

So you have to filter your radio buttons inside event listener. Something like this:

```
var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({

    events: {
        'click input[type="radio"]' : 'radioListener',
    },

    radioListener : function(evt) {
        var selectedObject =  evt.currentTarget;
        if (selectedObject.is(':checked')) {
            $(selectedObject).prop('checked', false);
            $(selectedObject).val('');
            $(selectedObject).change(this.clearSelection(evt));
        }
    }

});
```

Comment: Hi this code won't work as firefox sets the value to checked before the event is fired. selectedObject.is(':checked') will always be true. The event only fires in chrome and safari when the radio button is already checked. The event does not fire if the radio button is not checked.  E.g. user clicks on a checked radio button, the event is fired. This is the behaviour I am trying to replicate in firefox.

Comment: @James Owen You're right that the value sets to `checked` before the event is fired. But `selectedObject.is(':checked') ` is not always true. It's `true` when radio has been set to checked state from unchecked and it's `false` otherwise. So you can simply add negation operator to condition: `if (!selectedObject.is(':checked'))...`. Although your code in `radioListener` doesn't make sense (`checked` prop is already set to `false`).

Comment: Furthermore `$(selectedObject).change(this.clearSelection(evt));` doesn't make sense too. `this` in this context refers to `MyView` instance which has no `clearSelection` method. Also if you meant binding event listener, you have to pass function/method itself (`clearSelection`), not the returning value of function (as in your example).